# Using if statement in django template to detect a NULL

Tags: html, django

My web application stores dances and the YouTube link to that dance. The table shows the dance name and a link to the video which is passed to a new page to show the embedded video. This all works fine but some dances do not have a video and the return from the database for video_id is NULL.as below

http://localhost:8000/video_test/HjC9DidEwPc,%20Big%20Blue%20Tree  --- with video
or
http://localhost:8000/video_test/NULL,%20Baby%20Kate  ----  with no video

I want include a test for the null in the template which tabulates the dances so that the link does not appear if no video

tabulated output is the word video is a link to video_test

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| The dance name | Video |
| The dance name | Video |

I have tried using {% if i.video == NULL %}  is NULL,  is None, but none work.I have looked at various other questions which seem to suggest that one of the above should work. I either get an unable to parse error or the if statement has no effect.
.
Model

```
class Dances(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=120)
    video_id = models.CharField('video_id', max_length=50)
    level = models.CharField('level', max_length=3)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

view

```
def video_test(request, id, name):
 
    vid_id= id

    d_name = name
    return render(request, 'alineapp/video_test.html',{'vid_id':vid_id, 'd_name':d_name})
```

Template

```
<!--  Table for Beginner dances -->
    <table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">                      
                        
    {% for i in beg_list %}
    <tr>                          
    <td>{{ i.name }}</td>

    {% If i.video !== NULL %}

    <td><a  href="{% url 'video_test'   i.video_id i.name %}">Video</a></td>

    {% else %} 

    <td> None  </td>   
    {% endif %}     
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `not none`?

```
{% if i.video is not none %}
    <td><a  href="{% url 'video_test'   i.video_id i.name %}">Video</a></td>
{% else %} 
    <td> None  </td>   
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes and I got the following error: Invalid block tag on line 22: 'If', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: Is it because you have used ‘If’ instead of ‘if’. It should be lowercase!

Comment: I have got this to work by using   {% if i.video_id != 'NULL' %} I don't understand why NULL should be in quotation marks but it did work